# Comparing 16 bit numbers in nasm produces wrong results

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64

I have just started learning assembly. I am coding nasm in 32 bit mode. I am trying to compare 3 numbers  inputted by the user and print the largest number. However, I cannot seem to correctly compare the numbers if I only reserve 16 bits for each number using resb 2. I do, however, get correct results when I reserved 32 bits for the numbers using resw 2. I cannot understand why this is the case. Here is my code:

```
SYS_EXIT equ 1
SYS_WRITE equ 4
SYS_READ equ 3
STD_IN equ 0
STD_OUT equ 1

segment .data

    msg1 db "Enter first number",0xA
    msg1_len equ $- msg1

    msg2 db "Enter second number",0xA
    msg2_len equ $- msg2

    msg3 db "Enter third number",0xA
    msg3_len equ $- msg3

    msg4 db "Largest number is ",0xA
    msg4_len equ $- msg4

segment .bss

    num1 resb 2
    num2 resb 2
    num3 resb 2
    res resb 2

section .text

    global _start

_start:

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STD_OUT
    mov ecx, msg1
    mov edx, msg1_len
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STD_IN
    mov ecx, num1
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STD_OUT
    mov ecx, msg2
    mov edx, msg2_len
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STD_IN
    mov ecx, num2
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STD_OUT
    mov ecx, msg3
    mov edx, msg3_len
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STD_IN
    mov ecx, num3
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

    mov ecx, [num1]
    cmp ecx, [num2]
    jg check_third
    mov ecx, [num2]


check_third:

    cmp ecx, [num3]
    jg result
    mov ecx, [num3]

result:
    mov [res], ecx
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STD_OUT
    mov ecx, msg4
    mov edx, msg4_len
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STD_OUT
    mov ecx, res
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

exit:
    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    int 0x80
```

Sorry if it has a lot of repeating code. I understand why I need 2 bytes to store keyboard input when supposedly ascii characters are only 8 bits in length (Since the standard input will also read the new line character aside from the digit). However, I do not know a lot of things about how nasm works such as how it reacts when I move 16 bits of memory to a 32 bit register, how it compares 32 bit and 16 bit values (will it do signed expansion or just pad 0 before binary subtraction). I would truly appreciate it if someone can recommend me resources on the technicalities of nasm aside from explaining why I need to reserve 2 words to do the comparison.

Comment: Did you already step your program using a debugger? You may use this one which has been developed by me last year: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bindbg/

Comment: Thanks Martin!!! MykelXIII, what you get from the keyboard is an 8-bit character. What you get from `mov ecx, [num1]` (etc) is 32 bits - even if you've only reserved 16 bits! Either `movzx ecx, byte [num1]` or `mov cl, [num1]` should help - although you're still comparing characters, not numbers. It is not a "Nasm question" (but you might find examples around the Nasm Forum).

Comment: @FrankKotler I know Im just comparing characters, but since the ascii equivalent of 0 - 9 are ascending in value I assumed it would still compare correctly without converting them to their numerical equivalent. Lastly, does moving 32 bits instead of the 16 bits mean I was transferring memory that didnt belong to the part that I reserved? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Yes. Moving 32 bits will pick up both `num1` AND `num2`. That's why your results are odd. Switch to `cl` instead of `ecx` and it should "work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nasm does not keep record of the size of the data at label like some other assemblers. Suppose you enter 1, 2 and 3. Bytes stored at your labels will then be:

```
num1: db 0x31, 0x0A
num2: db 0x32, 0x0A
num3: db 0x33, 0x0A
```

When you move 32 bits of data from label `num1`, you are actually also moving data from `num2`. Because little endian machines store least significant bytes first, you get something like:

```
    mov ecx, 0x0A320A31 ; high bytes contain num2 and low bytes contain num1
    cmp ecx, 0x0A330A32 ; high bytes contain num3 and low bytes contain num2
    jg check_third
    mov ecx, 0x0A330A32  
check_third:
    cmp ecx, 0x00000A33 ; high bytes contain res and low bytes contain num3
    jg result
    .....
```

`resw 2` (or `resd 1`) would work because reserved memory is initialized to zeros. As Frank stated in the comment, you should use `cl` instead of `ecx` because 8 bits is all you need to handle in this case.

Comment: Accepting this answer. Very clear and great explanation. Thanks :)